# How to setup up a prerequisite in installer?

Tags: c#

how to setup up a prerequisite in installer?
the prerequisite are

1. SQL Server 2005
2. .NET Framework 3.5sp1
3. Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008

I want to run this three software before the system. If they exist, setup should continue. It any of these is missing, setup should install prerequisites as part of the installer.

Please guide me, step by step how to do it.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your setup project, properties, then : `required components` -> tick what you need to install, i'm not sure about the `crystal reports`, I think its in the `powerpack`.

However, this wont prevent installing, rather, it will install the components !

Second way of doing this is :
 right click on the setup project -> view -> `Launching conditions`
Then just add what you need. This will prevent setting up the application if conditions are not met.

PS : im translating from a non english VS, so translations are approximative