# Installing SQL server 2005 through windows c# setup project

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005-express

I have a windows c# application with its setup file. Now I wish to install SQL Server 2005 express edition while the setup of my application is being installed on any computer.
Is this possible ?
How ?

Comment: Very complex. I suggest you to try [LocalDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc) (if you can switch to more recent versions of SqlServer)

Comment: I have a code that installs a SQL server 2005 express edition exe file. But I dont know how to attach that file to the setup project so that sql gets installed while the setup runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set `Prequisities` to you setup for this.

Check the similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818885/how-to-setup-up-a-prerequisite-in-installer)

Comment: But does it install sql server if not present on the user machine ? or does it just checks if sql server is present or now ?

Comment: you have to set the option like Download online or from Folder

Comment: can you please explain in detail ? as i tried doing a number of things but they didnt work out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923439/how-to-add-sql-server-2008-express-to-list-of-prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can
Add **custom action** by right clicking **setup project** --> **view** --> **Custom Actions** --> right click **Custom Actions** --> Add Custom Actions.

Now  going to add the prerequisites for your setup project.

Select your **setup** project, right click and go to **properties**, then click the **Prerequisites** button.
there u can set url